# Plot stacked bar with calculated values in another column

Tags: plot

I have a dataframe which includes leads we generated everyday, columns are lead_id, generated_date, handled_date, termination_date, each row is one lead, if a lead has empty handled_date, that means this lead is still waiting to be handled, and the lead is available for later days before temination_date. I want to plot a stack bar which shows how many leads are available everyday, each stacked bar means on which day the lead is generated. the senario is:

1. on 20190413,we generate 100 leads, then on 20190413 we have one bar With height 100,
2. on 20190414, we generate 150 new leads, and 50 leads from previous day (20190413) are handled, so 50 left(no leads are terminated), in the graph,  20190414 should have 2 stacked bars, one is 50 (100-50) leads left from 20190413, another one is 150 New generated leads
3. on 20190415, we generate 100 leads, 30 leads from 20190413 are handled 'yesterday'(20190414, and no leads are terminated), 50 leads from 20190414 are handled also 'yesterday' (20190414), so in the graph, for 20190415 there should be 3 stacked bars, 20 (100-50-30) leads from 20190413, 100 (150-50) from 20190414, and 100 New generated leads.
   As long as it is before the termination_date, and the lead has empty value in column of handled_date, then this lead is availalbe.

Can anybody tell me how to plot? Thank you very much.

Comment: I want a stackbar , the xaxis means handl_date, the graph shows how many leads are avaialble to be handled on each handle_date, and each stacked bar means on which day the lead is generated, so in this way , i can see how fast the leads are consumed.

Comment: What program or language are you going to use? What have you attempted?

Comment: I am using pandas. Now I will try to create New columns for each of the handled_date, such as processed_20190413...., and then fill in the value on the condition: if  (the  lead has empty value in handled_date & genrated_date < 'processed_....' ,(title of New created column) &prcessed_...< termination_date,) then fill in With the value of when this lead was generated. In short, for each New created column, if the lead is generated before, and is empty With handled_date, and not Reach terminated date, then fill in value With the date when this lead was generated. Then use pivot table to plot.